# Grafana Drill Down Link on Gauge Panel

Tags: grafana

I'm apparently missing something obvious.  When I add a Drill Down link to a Gauge Panel in Grafana 6.2.1, it doesn't seem to attach to the panel anywhere.  If I change the panel to a graph, a small icon appears in the top left corner to follow the drill down link, but visualized as a gauge, that icon goes away.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything.

It is just not supported: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/17473

Some kind of a work-around would be to use a Text panel with the desired drill-down link, and place it right next to the gauge (e.g. as a title for the gauge)